# How to hide/show special price/regular price from magento admin section

Tags: magento

I want to hide regular price in case of special price applicable for the customer on magento based store and I successfully did that by editing "price.phtml". But, I want to give this capability to magento admin's hand so that he/she can hide or show regular price/special price.

Can anyone please suggest how to build custom module for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a Yes/No product attribute for that and then use that attribute on the frontend of the website to hide or not hide the price.

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for the idea! but as per my knowledge about magento, attribute is product specific but I want to create only one option in admin by using that option ye/no admin can show/hide regular price.

Comment: In that case I would create a very basic module that would only add an option in the Configuration system and then reference that option anywhere the price is displayed. You will want to look up the contents of a system.xml file in a module.

Comment: Will you please give me basic idea for this module please? Like how option from the configuration can be accessed where the price is displayed? Thanks!

Comment: I'd start with this blog post: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations